# Is it safe to remove the Bash Shell startup files for Samba user accounts?

Tags: bash, samba, startup-scripts

I'm in the process of setting up Samba shares for a SOHO network and would like to know whether or not it is safe/advisable to remove a Samba user's Bash Shell startup files (i.e. `.bash_logout`, `.bash_rc`, `.profile`).

Provided that the respective users are not allowed to logon to the system that Samba runs on (their login shell is set to `/bin/false`), is there any drawback I should be aware off when removing those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe to remove them.  They aren't even strictly necessary if someone logs in via a shell, as they are user-specific configs extending or overriding global settings set in e.g. `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Alright, exactely what I was hoping to hear.

Comment: Not to mention that `bash` is never used by a user with `/bin/false` shell.